# Hibernate: any difference between java.lang.Integer and int?

Tags: hibernate

Is there any noticeable difference between

```
<property name="pwdRetryCount" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="pwd_retry_count" />
</property>
```

and

```
<property name="pwdRetryCount" type="int">
    <column name="pwd_retry_count" />
</property>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They only have noticeable difference when handling null value.

It is because `int` is the primitive data type that cannot assign null to it while `java.lang.Integer` is the wrapper class of  `int`  which can accept null .

So , if `pwd_retry_count` column is nullable and you use  `int` to map your entity object , for the record which  `pwd_retry_count` is null , error occurs as  `int` cannot store null.

Comment: The answer is totally correct, but consider that, based on "Effective Java", in the case you can both of them, using primitive type  prefers to wrapper class (item 61)

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is totally correct and I just type extra info.

Use nullable types (boxed primitive types like Integer, Double, etc.) for optional values. It depends on your model if it makes sense for particular value to be optional. If it has to have default values, you can create @PreX callbacks (for example @PreLoad) or override getter for returning primitive type with default value instead.

Use primitive types for required value. It has some great benefits if you distinguish among these two approaches like:

1. If you let hibernate generate DDL, it will automatically create not null constraints for primitive types.
2. If you do mapping among web dto objects and entities, you have implicit NPE which indicates problem in your code and that behaviour will not make your data inconsistent.

There is one interesting thing though. If you use Lombok library and like to use @Getter and @Setter on entities and you control SelectBeforeInsert behaviour with Persistable interface then you should always use big boxed type like Integer, because you cannot do genericity with primitive type like `Persistable<int>`. If you use `Persistable<Integer>` + lombok's @Getter + your ID is named like "id" then you have implicit override getter method for getId. It is just symbiose among lombok + jpa entity.